# Как применять разные хедеры в зависимости от запроса Retrofit2

Tags: java, retrofit, kotlin, retrofit2

Есть к примеру 2 запроса первый с хедером `api_key`, второй без него

Добавляю я хедер в интерсепторе `ApiInterceptor` http клиента

Выглядит вот так(работаю с даггером)

```
@Provides
@NetworkScope
fun provideHttpClient(iLoggingInterceptor: HttpLoggingInterceptor, iCache: Cache, iApiInterceptor: ApiInterceptor): OkHttpClient
{
    return OkHttpClient.Builder() //
            .addInterceptor(iLoggingInterceptor) //
            .addInterceptor(iApiInterceptor) //
            .connectTimeout(API.TIMEOUT_IN_MS.value.toLong(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) //
            .cache(iCache) //
            .build()
}
```

То есть тут я получил свой `OkHttpClient` с `ApiInterceptor`

внутри этого `ApiInterceptor` я и добавляю нужный хедер

```
@Suppress("NULLABILITY_MISMATCH_BASED_ON_JAVA_ANNOTATIONS")
class ApiInterceptor: Interceptor
{
override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response?
{
    val original: Request = chain.request()
    val originalHttpUrl: HttpUrl = original.url()

    val url: HttpUrl? = with(originalHttpUrl.newBuilder()) {
        addQueryParameter("api_key", API.KEY.value)
        build()
    }

    val requestBuilder: Request.Builder = original.newBuilder().url(url)
    val request: Request? = requestBuilder.build()

    return chain.proceed(request)
}
}
```

и все вроде хорошо, но получается, что теперь этот хедер летит со всеми запросами которые в нем не нуждаются.

Теперь получается, что нужно делать для каждого запроса свой интерсептер и перестраивать http клиент , либо все же есть другой способ?

Я вот нашел [такую ссылку](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/452) в конце которой точно такой же впрос

И там советуют добавить такое к апи

```
@Headers({
  "Sign-Request: true"
})
```

Но, теперь не совсем ясно как все таки организовать эти хедеры, если в одном запросе они одни , а в другом другие...

Подскажите кто работает с ретрофитом

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А что мешает описать метод в интерфейсе ретрофита с заголовком как параметр?
Если передавать с параметром `null`, то заголовок передаваться не будет.

Котлин со значением параметра по умолчанию сюда вообще отлично вписывается.

Документация:
https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/index.html?retrofit2/http/Header.html

Answer (score 0):

Вроде как единственный способ - в интерсепторе проверять `url` не добавлять заголовок если он (`url`) входит с список, заранее созданный, урлов, коим заголовок не нужен.